# pass data to previous view without segue,@IBaction swift

Tags: swift, xcode7, parameter-passing, segue

I have a View1 when i click on textbox i am going to view2(table view) to pick a value. I want to send the picked value to view1 for that textbox.

The controls are created programmatically so i am not using segue,IBActions.

I am trying to use the protocol methods still no success. Here is what i have tried.

```
class DynamicSuperView: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,dropdownDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate
{

 func setValue(value:AnyObject)
 {
  print("dynamic view delegate method executed")
    self.labelText =  value as! String
    //return selectedValue;
  }

override func viewDidLoad() {

}
}
```

The second class is here with delegate method..

```
protocol dropdownDelegate {
  func setValue(value: AnyObject);
}


class testClass: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {
  var delegate:dropdownDelegate! = nil

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vcName = names[indexPath.row]
    print ("Table view cell clicked and value passed: \(vcName)")

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

    }

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    delegate.setValue(value: "Testing delegate")

}

}
```

Once i select the value in the tableview i am calling the delegate method and trying to pass that value but no success.

I don't want to create the new instance of the previous view controller because i will lose the data already entered by the user, so i am popping the current view controller and going to the previous view controller.

Please suggest if my approach i correct or not?

ERROR: 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thank you in advance

Comment: How are you going from one view to the other without segue?

Comment: When a textbox is edited i am calling the below func to navigate to other view         

                                        func ButtonPressed()
    {
        
        print("Button Pressed!!")
        
        // This will create the new instance of the view controller.
        
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storage") as! testClass
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
view func ButtonPressed() { 

print("Button Pressed!!") // This will create the new instance of the view controller. 

let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storage") as! testClass 

vc.delegate = self

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true) 
}
```

You are not setting the delegate to first view controller.

Comment: I did this but this is not executing the protocol method.
There is no error as well

Comment: If i am going to ViewCOntroller2 using a button touch down event then only delegate is executing. I want it for UITextBox events

This flow is working.
ViewController1--> Button(onclick) --> show ViewController2 on selecting the value delegate is executing.

This flow is not working
ViewController1--> UIText(onclick) --> show ViewController2 on selecting the value delegate is executing.


     dynamicTxtField.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonPressed", for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)

  dynamicTxtField.addTarget(self, action: "ButtonPressed", for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)